# Puppeteer discord bot keeps crashing when hosted on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, discord.js, puppeteer

Bot works fine locally and even in the simlulated Heroku local `heroku local web`, but crashes after a minute or two when hosted on their servers online.

- I have installed the buildpack for puppeteer:
  https://github.com/jontewks/puppeteer-heroku-buildpack
- I cleared my build cache:
  https://help.heroku.com/18PI5RSY/how-do-i-clear-the-build-cache
- I have tried to manually set my worker scaling to 1  `heroku ps:scale web=1`
- This is my puppeteer browser launch arguments: `{args: ["--no-sandbox", "--disable-setuid-sandbox"],}`

---

### List of my dependencies below:

- discord.js
- dotenv
- node-fetch
- puppeteer
- fs

---

**Logs are useless:**

```
2020-05-15T11:40:56.804117+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-05-15T11:41:22.345051+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-05-15T11:41:22.345073+00:00 app[web.1]: > discordbot@1.0.0 start /app
2020-05-15T11:41:22.345073+00:00 app[web.1]: > node bot.js
2020-05-15T11:41:22.345074+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-05-15T11:42:20.278141+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-05-15T11:53:02.553013+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-05-15T11:53:25.758932+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-05-15T11:53:25.758955+00:00 app[web.1]: > discordbot@1.0.0 start /app
2020-05-15T11:53:25.758956+00:00 app[web.1]: > node bot.js
2020-05-15T11:53:25.758956+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-05-15T11:54:18.310840+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

Comment: —disable-dev-shm-usage

Comment: Found on https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-google-chrome/issues/37#issue-288093988

Comment: Didn't fix my issue

Comment: print the logs from the heroku dashboard

Comment: I did, it rapports the same as the logs you see in my post. No details about the actual crash other than changing state from starting to crashed

Comment: Not really a solution, but I recommend moving to [Glitch](http://glitch.com/)

Comment: I tried glitch and it works, i have no idea why it needs to be so complicated to make it work on Heroku.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and applied this:
(Copied from Puppeteer Troubleshooting site. And It worked!)

Running Puppeteer on Heroku

Running Puppeteer on Heroku requires some additional dependencies that aren't included on the Linux box that Heroku spins up for you. To add the dependencies on deploy, add the Puppeteer Heroku buildpack to the list of buildpacks for your app under Settings > Buildpacks.

The url for the buildpack is https://github.com/jontewks/puppeteer-heroku-buildpack

Ensure that you're using '--no-sandbox' mode when launching Puppeteer. This can be done by passing it as an argument to your .launch() call: puppeteer.launch({ args: ['--no-sandbox'] });.

When you click add buildpack, simply paste that url into the input, and click save. On the next deploy, your app will also install the dependencies that Puppeteer needs to run.

If you need to render Chinese, Japanese, or Korean characters you may need to use a buildpack with additional font files like https://github.com/CoffeeAndCode/puppeteer-heroku-buildpack

There's also another simple guide from @timleland that includes a sample project: https://timleland.com/headless-chrome-on-heroku/.